# How to apply color changes of buttons with javascript and Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create button effect in which will change its color on click and returns to its original colour after the click.

A conditional was added within the button effect to returns to its original code.

In this case I have four variables storing each color and instantiates for each button id in HTML.

```
// VARIABLES - ids from DOM instantiated as querySelector().

const btnBlue = document.querySelectorAll("#btnBlue");
const btnGreen = document.querySelectorAll("#btnGreen");
const btnRed = document.querySelectorAll("#btnRed");
const btnYellow = document.querySelectorAll("#btnYellow");
```

Giving an example of a button here is where I am stuck with the logic.

```
// Exemple with blue button:
$(btnBlue).click(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#00FFFF');
    // the play() func does other logic such as join other functions 
    // together and flash all the buttons in different order.
    blueBtnAudio.play();
    if(btnBlue == '#00FFFF' ){
      $(btnBlue).stop();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Have a look at `mousedown` and `mouseup` https://api.jquery.com/mousedown/

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for any JS here. You can do this with CSS alone by using the `:active` pseudo-selector:

```css
button {
  background-color: #CCC;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  outline: 0;
}

button:active {
  background-color: #C00;
  color: #EEE;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
```

Comment: Lovely, thank you very much for the answer!! It indeed worked but I need this effect to be added into JS to after callback into another function that will create random sequences to be played (simon game).

Comment: Glad it helped, however I would suggest starting a new question which includes the use case for the button.

Comment: Ok, it makes sense. Appreciated your help.